# Show how many online users could answer the question

Tags: feature-request, questions

If I write a question with tags [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json), etc., I would like to know how many users subscribed to those tags are currently online. This may also be a kind of probability that my question will be answered.

If the chance to get an answer is too small, my question will get not enough attention and will get lost, so I would be better to post the question some time later (I know about bounty...).

*This feature can be especially helpful for the **beginners**.* I think that this feature can greatly reduce the number of unanswered questions, since the user receives the feedback:

> there are too few users online who can answer your question

Comment: Given that this is your feature request, do bear in mind that the onus is on you to describe the benefits as you see them.

Comment: What if none answers? Request a list, so you can send them a PM? Keep editing your question to bump it up to the front page until someone answers?

Comment: Subscribers does not equate to potential answer providers.  Some may subscribe to a tag in order to learn from the Qs and As posted.  The notion of "online" needs work too.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you ask a question, even though you may have an immediate need, that question is intended to live on as permanent content on the site. Please do not decide against asking it just because you worry it may not get an immediate answer. We have edit activity, and more importantly, the bounty system to bring attention to questions not receiving sufficient attention.

Comment: I am against this idea because it will likely add more whining in comments or on meta. *There were **14** users seen in the last 15 mins when I asked and **no one would help me** with my bunny question*

Comment: @dit please keep meta-complaints out of your question - if people want to downvote, they will (and should!)

Comment: Would you rather have a quick answer from the first available person or a good answer from someone who finds the question a week later?

Comment: The key problem is that the premise in your title (*"Show how many online users could answer the question"*) is not necessarily supported by the feature you're requesting. Just following the tags doesn't mean they a user can answer your question (and not following it doesn't mean they can't). Lots of "online" followers of a tag does not necessarily mean that a question will get answered any more (or less) quickly. Some questions can be answered immediately by a single user stumbling across it, some may take much more time and numerous contributors. Focus on writing good questions!

Comment: as usual, power users have the say. ok I belive anyway it would be helpful :/

Comment: You may answer a question without having subscribed to the tags it lists. I don't really use tag subscription myself and I've answered several questions.

Comment: @dit everyone **who turns up** gets a say!

Comment: @dit those comments are full of reasons *why* we don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: @dit I believe you when you say that you believe it would be helpful, however you did not bring any specific reason or proof for your belief. You are also focusing to much on the good side and ignoring the draw backs of such a system. I think you should take a step back and make some more thoughts about this. You need to view it from both perspectives.

Comment: I can't add much, but like the other commenters/posters, I think this proposal sucks.

Comment: If this is implemented, most probably it will give **false hope** to the askers when they don't get any answers. And worse is, they won't ask if there's no answerer. The disadvantage weights more than the usefullness. And all other comments above.

Comment: @Plutonix What is a bunny question? What nature of the rabbit are you relating to these questions? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295127/what-are-bunny-questions

Comment: @Nattrass, I picked that up from somewhere and take it to be a play on the ski term *bunny slope* which refers to a very easy, gentle hill for beginners.  Basically a question almost anyone can answer.

Answer (score 16):

I do not think this is a good idea for several reasons.

- Someone subscribed to a tag does not mean they are able to answer it. They may have a passing interest in the topic and want to see new questions related to the topic. They may be researching a new technology and watching tags within that technology.
- Immediate answers are helpful to the person who asked the question, but we aren't here *just* to help them. We're here to help future visitors as well. If a question takes hours or days to answer, but provides a solution that will help others, it is a successful question.
- I believe that knowing that people are online that could answer a question will increase the noise. If you post a question in a populate tag with thousands or tens of thousands of subscribers and you still don't get an answer, what is the first reaction you imagine the asker will have?

> Why didn't **one** of the 4,000 people on line help me?!

It could be because the question is incredibly localized to their code base. It could be because they pasted a 500 line block of code. It could be become someone [lost their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/186281).

It could be for a variety of reasons that they weren't answered immediately. But, to the user, it looks like they were ignored. Instead of being patient, improving their question, or doing further research, they now are frustrated and upset that a community of people has ignored them and they don't know why.

Comment: Tim lost his keys AGAIN? Seriously... I hope he just removed the lock on his door by now

Comment: it should be just a hint or recommendation to post the question some time later. it's all about data mining. I'm not sure but I believe the more user are online, the higher the chance to get an better answer.

Comment: @dit then a first step might be trying to validate that assumption, via e.g. http://data.stackexchange.com/. Is there a correlation between peaks of activity in a given tag and the length of time questions in that tag take to be answered? *"In God we trust; all others bring data"*!

Answer (score 7):

@Andy pretty much summed up what I was going to answer with, but I have a little bit to add.

How do we define "online"? Activity in the last 5 minutes? last hour? last day? has an SO account? How we define that shows how accurate that number could possibly be under the best of circumstances (sure there may be 10k users on but you have such an esoteric or poorly described problem that none of them can actually answer).

Also, what about people that don't follow a tag but could answer?  For example, I don't follow any tags right now, but I can answer a lot of questions in SQL, most of a .Net web stack, HTML, CSS, javascript, etc.  Is the fact that I (presumably along with others) don't show up in the answerer number going to cause people to not ask questions? The accuracy of that number can't be all that good.  Even as just a heuristic it might be OK at best, but since you seem to feel that this would be targeted at beginners, they are the people least likely to understand how good / bad of a heuristic it really is.

Also, the idea of discouraging asking based on how many people are online bothers me.  We never want to discourage people from asking questions (and by that I mean good questions, we actively try to discourage asking garbage questions).  We are trying to build up a repository of knowledge.  Questions are the lifeblood of the site.  Getting less of them can't possibly be a good thing.

In addition, what happens between tags with huge followings vs. very small tags?  For example, at the time of writing, the C# tag has 56.6k followers.  The R tag has 8k followers, d3.js has 1.9k and Flattr has 19.  We want questions in all those tags, especially the smaller tags in order to build those communities.  What about new technologies, where there aren't a lot of followers yet, but we really want to build those up? Are people going to not want to ask questions in new/small tags because the may not get answers?

Another thing, will this encourage mis-tagging questions just to get eyes on it? (Not saying that couldn't happen now, it just becomes much more appealing when you can see that adding another tag could boost the number of people looking at your question by a few orders of magnitude.)

I can see why you believe this might attract questions and help people get answers and then want to keep contributing to the community.  However I feel like the downsides to this are numerous and far outweigh the potential good.