# What are 'Bunny Questions'?

Tags: discussion, meta

Meta Meta Question time.

In the post below..

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295096/how-to-easily-gain-reputation-in-stack-overflow

in the comments section...

Plutonix states that "Other than bunny questions rep isnt always easy to gain"

I've searched meta.stackoverflow.com for bunny questions but am no wiser and have no hits. What is Plutonix talking about?

The comments section is locked on the question, so I can't ask Plutonix on that thread.

Comment: It would probably be better to comment on that question and *ask Plutonix what they mean*; I'd guess they mean trivial, but I can't be certain.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would, but the comments section is locked

Comment: So it is, sorry.

Comment: I guess it must be some turn of phrase he has come up with. I thought I was missing out on some SO lingo.

Comment: Here's another comment where s/he use the same phrase: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289897/show-how-many-online-users-could-answer-the-question#comment174995_289897

Comment: That comment section is still unlocked; perhaps ask on it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe good call. I shall report my findings back here.

Comment: I would have thought that a Bunny question on SO would be about Bugs.  :-)

Answer (score 6):

**Bunny Question**

> 1. [Plutonix] "A play on the ski term bunny slope which refers to a very easy, gentle hill for beginners. A question almost anyone can answer."

**References**

Plutonix, [Show how many online users could answer the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289897/show-how-many-online-users-could-answer-the-question#comment174995_289897)